# How to print this object in Angular inside div tag

Tags: angular, ionic3

How can I show this object in Angular inside a div tab, this object have number index

```
testData :any =  [
                    { 
                       "0": { "id":"1",  "name":"Mandatory Learning FY_201" },
                       "1": { "id":"2",  "name":"Mandatory Learning FY_202" },
                       "2": { "id":"1",  "name":"Mandatory Learning FY_203" },
                       "3": { "id":"2",  "name":"Mandatory Learning FY_204" },                        
                       "4": { "id":"1",  "name":"Mandatory Learning FY_205" } 
                    }
                 ];
```

Comment: You can simply convert/flatten this to array of objects and then iterate in your html using ngFor

Comment: `{{ testData | json }}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend first to transform your object into collection and then render it using standard `*ngFor` syntax:

```
testDataArray = Object.keys(testData[0]).map(key => testData[0][key])

<div *ngFor="let item of testDataArray">
  {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Or

Use angular built in pipe named `KeyValuePipe` (require >= Angular 6):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of testData[0] | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}: {{item.value.id}} - {{item.value.name}}
</div>
```

[Angular KeyValuePipe documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)